# A lot of assertions missing after upgrading to PHPUnit 8

Tags: phpunit, assertion

I'm working on upgrading our codebase.

In this process I upgraded PHPUnit from 7 to 9. This decreased our assertions quite drastically.

I downgraded to PHPUnit 8 to see what happened, they were still gone.
Downgrading back to PHPUnit 7 made them 'popup' again.

I've ran the checks with '--debug' and compared the output. This does not show tests being skipped. I also don't see much difference in other metrics... Code coverage is the similar as well.

PHPUnit 7:

```
Time: 14.08 minutes, Memory: 1.71 GB
OK, but incomplete, skipped, or risky tests!
Tests: 2053, Assertions: 143695, Skipped: 56.
```

PHPUnit 8:

```
Time: 16.14 minutes, Memory: 1.31 GB
OK, but incomplete, skipped, or risky tests!
Tests: 2053, Assertions: 22304, Skipped: 56, Risky: 56.
```

We have some tests which run 'optionally'. So if a setting isn't true, they're skipped. This is marked as 'risky' in PHPUnit 8 and I plan to address that later. However that should not impact the number of assertions as in both cases the tests isn't running.

I've looked at the changelog (https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/8.0.0/ChangeLog-8.0.md#800---2019-02-01) but that doesn't really help me.

It would be great if somebody could help me to figure out if this is a problem, or a change in PHPUnit which I could safely ignore.

---

**Update:**

I've added a tearDown function which echos '$this->getCount() and $this->getNumAssertions()'. This shows the following numbers. The getNumAssertions is mostly 0, so I guess this is not the right place to call it or the right way to use it.

PHPUnit 7:

```
ERRORS!
Tests: 2053, Assertions: 142339, Errors: 3, Skipped: 67.
Sum of 'getCount' results: 22341
```

PHPUnit 8:

```
ERRORS!
Tests: 2053, Assertions: 22641, Errors: 2, Skipped: 67.
Sum of 'getCount' results: 22342
```

PS: Numbers are a bit different compared to the first results, but I've worked on some tests in the meanwhile.

Interesting thing here is that the getCount results for PHPUnit7, PHPUnit8 and the total for PHPUnit 8 are comparable. Still no explanation for the missing assertions though.